# Magento cron job issue

Tags: magento, cron

I am having email sending issue in magento and I think it is due to cron jobs, following are the setting

[image: crpn.php file on server]

cron job settings on cpanel

[image]

cron job settings on magento
[image]

I just cant figure out the issye

Comment: Can you tell me your magento version?

Comment: im using version 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

To Set Cron on Server:

You can set cron job on server for every 5 minutes:

```
php -f /home/fullpath/public_html/cron.php
```

Debug:

If cron Job still not work, Please add following code:

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

After below line of code:

```
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```